# How can I add my personal abbreviation to emmet-mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I'm using emmet-mode in Emacs24.

I want to expand `php` to `<?php ?>`, but Emmet doesn't support php abbreviation.

I thought if I insert a line `(puthash "php" "<?php ?>;" tbl)` between some other addreviation, but it doesn't work. Above all I don't want to write directly `emmet-mode.el`.

How can I define my abbreviation outside of mode elisp file?

Comment: Did you try M-x add-mode-abbrev?

Comment: I didn't know it. I'll try it either. Thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `yasnippet` for that. Anyway, for `emmet-mode`:

```
(puthash "pp" "<?php ${child} ?>" emmet-tag-snippets-table)
```

As far as I understand, all the preferences for `emmet-mode` is contained in the hash table `emmet-snippets`, it then contains nested hash table for per mode specific snippets and aliases.

```
emmet-snippets = {
  "html": {
    "snippets": {...}
    "aliases": {...}
  },
  "css": {
    "snippets": {...}
    "aliases": {...}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your info! I'll use yasnippet. It seems to be pretty match my situation.

Comment: That inner `gethash` call can be replaced with `emmet-tag-snippets-table`. (There's also `emmet-tag-aliases-table` and `emmet-css-snippets`.)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>M-x add-mode-abbrev</kbd> works here with `emmet-mode`.

There is an inconvenience from `add-mode-abbrev`, as its uses `backward-word` internally to catch the expansion wanted. Thus call it without numeric argument, which will default to numeric arg 1, it will bind "php ?>" as expansion. Than <kbd>M-x edit-abbrevs RET</kbd> and fix that.